# How to run a Flask application on port 80 while a venv is active?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

There are multiple questions and answers about running Flask applications on port 80, but none address the issue of `venv`.

Typically the answer quoted is to run the application as root.

This is ok as a solution as it doesn't require any special system configuration, but on the other hand isn't viable in many cases if the user doesn't have access to `sudo` or the root account.

In this particular case, although I do have access to `sudo`, I am running Python 3 with a virtual environment. That means that just running `sudo ./my_flask_thing` doesn't work. This is a Debian 12 system, so there isn't much in the way of alternatives. (eg: no system wide `pip3 install flask`)

How can I run a Flask application on port 80 in this particular case?

One solution which occured to me which doesn't require anything in the way of Python would be to run some kind of application which forwards requests to port 80 to port 5000 (the Flask default).

I'm not sure if this would work, or how it could be done. This could *perhaps* be done with iptables, but I am not sure at this time.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason *a priori* why "I'm running a virtual environment" would change absolutely anything whatsoever about how this works. We would need a proper [mre] in order to see an actual problem. If your Python process needs to run with a specific Python installation - whether or not that's a venv - as root, then run that Python as root. If it's a venv, then **activate the venv as root**. But first, make absolutely sure that you really do need that privilege. Permissions exist for a reason.

Comment: "That means that just running `sudo ./my_flask_thing` doesn't work." Well, maybe that could be fixed, if we had some idea of the contents of the `./my_flask_thing` script... ? Is that just the top-level Python script without an extension, or is it something that tries to activate the venv first, or *just what*?

Comment: "This is a Debian 12 system, so there isn't much in the way of alternatives. (eg: no system wide pip3 install flask)" - there are a million different Linuxes with comparable default restrictions, for good reason. Generally you can add Pip to the system Python with the system package manager, but generally you shouldn't as it increases the risk exposure surface for any malware that makes it on to PyPI.

Comment: Apologies; root users will ignore the virtualenv activation in terms of locating Python. But configuring `PATH` (and clearing out `PYTHONHOME`) is the *only meaningful thing that activating a virtualenv actually does* (the rest is cosmetic - read the `activate` script if you don't believe me); so just explicitly specify the path to the virtualenv's Python executable.

Answer (score -2):

One way to do it would be to install and configure a reverse proxy with nginx. Presumably nginx would have to be run with root privilages, but this would be ok as a solution.

Comment: Gave up. Just changed the url to ask for port 5000. Much easier solution

Comment: This is an absurd circumlocution around what should be a non-problem.